# Prevent images from wrapping but use scrolling

Tags: html, scroll, overflow, css

In the code below I have 3 images. I want to confine the width of the container to 300px. When the total number of images exceeds this width, I want to let the user scroll horizontally to vew the images. My code however is causing the images to wrap. Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AndroidDev/Asu7V/10/

```
<div style="width:300px; overflow-x: scroll">
    <div style="">
        <div class="x">
            <img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/avatar_dae559818d30_128.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="x">
            <img src="http://scottsdalepethotel.com/wp-content/uploads/et_temp/cat-648150_128x128.jpg" />
            <img src="http://playgo.ro/wp-content/themes/play3.0/play.png" style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0" />
        </div>
        <div class="x">
            <img src="http://blog.sureflap.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Maru.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap;` on the parent element which will force the elements not to wrap up if they fall short of parent `width`. And I've changed `overflow-x: scroll;` to `overflow-x: auto;` so that it doesn't show unnecessary scrollbar if the images are not exceeding the parent element. Just a tweak for a better UI, if not, you can use `overflow-x: scroll;` as well..

```
<div style="width:300px; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Asu7V/11/)

Also, don't use inline styles, consider using `class` and `id` instead.